# What regular expression will match a string of letter "U"s and letter "O"s where at most one pair of (U, O) or (O, U) appear next to each-other?

Tags: regex, regular-language

What regular expression will match a string of letter `U`s and `O` so that at most one letter `U` is adjacent to a letter `O`?

We wish to match strings of text such as `OOOOUUUU` and `UUUUOOO`.

However, the `U`s and `O`s should not touch each-other much, as in `OUOUUUOOO`

| **STRING** | **IS_MATCH** |
| --- | --- |
| empty string | **no** |
| `U` | yes |
| `O` | yes |
| `UUUU` | yes |
| `OOOO` | yes |
| `OU` | yes |
| `UO`, | yes |
| `UUUOOOO` | yes |
| `OOOOUUU` | yes |
| `OOOUUUUOOUOU` | **no** |
| `OUUUOOOUUUO` | **no** |
| `OUOUOUOUOUOUOU` | **no** |

---

The letters `O` and `U` should appear consecutively, at most once.

---

Suppose that **AS** is a collection of string literals such that for any string **A** in set **AS**, we have that our ideal regex **R** matches string literal **A**.

```
AS = {"U", "O", "OU", "UO", "UOO", "OOU", "UUO", "OOU", ...}
```

Let **A** be a string in collection **AS**.

It follows that if `UO` is a sub-sequence of string **A** then `OU` is **NOT** a subsequence of string  **A**.

Additionally, if `OU` is a sub-sequence of string **A** then `UO` is **NOT** a subsequence of string  **A**.

---

Comment: Can you show us your attempt please? This is a rather simple exercise needing only concatenation, repetition and alternation.

Answer (score 1):

Use an alternation for O's then any U's, or visa versa:

```
^(O+U*|U+O*)$
```

See [live demo](https://rubular.com/r/6pWZYEh9Fm0QzN).

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that we wish to confirm that a given string is valid, namely it:

- contains only `"O"`'s and `"U"`'s; and
- may not contain both substrings `"OU"` and `"UO"`.

---

One way to do that is to employ a negative lookahead (provided that feature is supported by the regex engine being used):

```
^(?!.*(?:OU+O|UO+U))[OU]+$
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/QHyGlq/1)

This expression can be broken down as follows.

```
^            match beginning of string
(?!          begin a negative lookahead
  .*         match >= 0 characters other than line terminators
  (?:        begin a non-capture group
    OU+O     match two 'O's separate by one or more 'U's
    |        or
    UO+U     match two 'U's separate by one or more 'O's
  )          end non-capture group
)            end negative lookahead
[OU]+        match >= 1 characters in character class
$            match end of string
```

One can also hover the cursor over each part of this expression at this link to obtain an explanation of its function.

Comment: This is a really overcomplicated and probably inefficient solution.

Comment: @Bergi, I didn't claim this to be the "best" solution in any sense, just a different way of doing it, which I thought had instructional value. I prefer Bohemian's earlier solution and contributed the sole upvote it has received so far. More generally, many complex regexes proposed as solutions to SO questions would never be used in practice, but that does not mean they do not have educational value. Nonetheless, I've edited my answer to retain just part of what I had previously. I do appreciate your comment; it brings a whiff of fresh air to a part of SO that often is stifling.